# Как отловить потерю фокуса с компонента и изменить значение при выборе не только в компоненте, а и в привязке?

Tags: angular2, angular, angular4, angular5

Есть компонент улучшенный dropbox и он выводит данные и потом я хочу передать выбранное значение вверх и при потере фокуса скрыть выпадающий список.  Вот код

```
import { Component, Input, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dropbox-comp',
  templateUrl: './dropbox.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dropbox.component.scss']
})
export class DropboxComponent{
  @Input() selected: object;
  @Input() array: [];

  public isOpen = false;

  constructor() { }

  toggle(){
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
  }

  change_value(item){
    this.selected = item;
  }

  @HostListener("blur") //Не работает
  lostfocus(){
    this.isOpen = false;
  }

}
```

Разметка

```
<div class="dropdown selectDropdown" [ngClass]="{'open': isOpen}" (click)="toggle()" (blur)="lostfocus()">
  <ul (blur)="lostfocus()">
    <li *ngFor="let item of array; let i = index" (click)="change_value(item)"><a>{{item.name}}</a></li>
  </ul>
  <span>{{selected['name']}}</span>
</div>
```

подключение

```
    <app-dropbox-comp [array]="store['sortCarsParameters']['data']"  
 [selected]="store['sortCarsParameters']['selected']"></app-dropbox-comp>
```

**Вопрос:

1) Если я уйду с компонента - я не могу его "закрыть"

2) Выбранное значение остаётся выбрано внутри компонента, но не выходит наверх по типу двойного связывания и [selected]="store['sortCarsParameters']['selected']"   остаётся тем же. Как изменить это значение?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, `@HostListener` не отработает на компоненте, который не может получить фокус. Поэтому и на `div` и на  `ul` он не сработает. Можете на желаемый элемент установить `tabIndex=0` в html, или повесить его сразу на хоста. Внизу приведу пример с установкой атрибута на компонент.

Во-вторых, двойное связывание предполагает исходящий ивент. У вас компонент только принимает значения с помощью директивы `@Input()` и квадратных скобок в темплейте.

Поэтому добавляем в компонент `@Output`.

```
import { Attribute, Component, Input, HostListener, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dropbox-comp',
  templateUrl: './dropbox.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dropbox.component.scss']
})
export class DropboxComponent{
  @Input() selected: object;
  @Input() array: [];

  @Output() selectedChange = new EventEmitter<object>();

  public isOpen = false;

  constructor(@Attribute('tabindex') public tabIndex: number = 0) {}

  toggle(){
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
  }

  change_value(item){
    this.selectedChange.emit(item);
  }

  @HostListener("blur") //Не работает
  lostfocus(){
    this.isOpen = false;
  }

}
```

В подключении можно сделать теперь двухсторонний биндинг `[(...)]`.

```
<app-dropbox-comp [array]="store.sortCarsParameters.data" 
                  [(selected)]="store.sortCarsParameters.selected">
</app-dropbox-comp>
```

Или с разделением биндингов:

```
<app-dropbox-comp [array]="store.sortCarsParameters.data" 
                  [selected]="store.sortCarsParameters.selected"
                  (selectedChange)="updateSelected(/*здесь обрабатывайте изменение данных*/)">
</app-dropbox-comp>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Только я не очень понял для чего @Attribute. Попробовал без него и работает всё-равно. А как подвязаться к событию, по типу если изменились данные, то вызови функцию "Загрузки данных", только что б универсально было и это подвязать в разметке главного компонента, так как dropbox-ов будет много и при обновлении запускать функцию в главном компоненте

Comment: если вы установили `tabIndex` на `div`, который заворачивает весь список, то да, можно без `@Attribute`. Но по сути, этот  `div` - лишняя обертка. Сам хост-компонент вполне может быть той самой оберткой. И тогда на него надо будет установить атрибут индекса. Подвязаться к исходящему событию можно просто разделив двухсторонний биндинг. Дополнил ответ

Comment: разобрался (selectedChange)="myfunc_data_Changed($event)" в разметке главного компонента и таким образом сообщаю, что данные. Вдруг кому будет интересно решение. Спасибо большое. Уже не первый раз выручаете)))))

Comment: А ещё вопрос. А по поводу потери фокуса не подскажете?

Comment: Задавайте, это ж не чат) сразу пишите вопрос)